# Object Type not recognized in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to embed a C# code in aspx page as below:

```
<% AssessmentFactor af = new AssessmentFactor (); %>
```

However, I am getting the `"The type or namespace name 'AssessmentFactor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"` Error, although it is working fine in the code behind

Anybody knows what is the problem ?

Comment: Can you try specifying the full type, including namespaces?

Comment: This is the name space of the "AssessmsntFactor" Class: namespace EmployeeInfo.EIM.HRD.Assessment

Comment: I mean add fully qualified name to your code: `<% EmployeeInfo.EIM.HRD.Assessment.AssessmentFactor af = new EmployeeInfo.EIM.HRD.Assessment.AssessmentFactor (); %>` and check if you still see the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import namespaces to your page like this:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="EmployeeInfo.EIM.HRD.Assessment" %>
```

And that should fix your problem. Alternatively, you can just specify the type with the full namespace:

```
<% EmployeeInfo.EIM.HRD.Assessment.AssessmentFactor af = new EmployeeInfo.EIM.HRD.Assessment.AssessmentFactor (); %>
```